# How to combine these three methods into one

Tags: scala, methods

I'm using [parboiled](http://parboiled.org/) to write a parser. I defined some methods as:

```
def InlineCharsBefore(sep: String) 
    = rule { zeroOrMore(!str(sep) ~ InlineChar) }
def InlineCharsBefore(sep1: String, sep2: String) 
    = rule { zeroOrMore((!str(sep1) | !str(sep2)) ~ InlineChar) }
def InlineCharsBefore(sep1: String, sep2: String, sep3: String) 
    = rule { zeroOrMore((!str(sep1) | !str(sep2) | !str(sep3)) ~ InlineChar) }
```

You can see they are very similar. I want to combine them into one, but I don't know how to do it. Maybe it should be:

```
def InlineCharsBefore(seps: String*) = rule { ??? }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vararg version can be implemented as:

```
 def InlineCharsBefore( seps: String* ) = {
   val sepMatch = seps.map( s => ! str(s) ).reduceLeft( _ | _ )
   rule { zeroOrMore( sepMatch ~ InlineChar) }
 }
```

However, I don't use *parboiled* so I cannot test it.